# How to fix 'cannot find symbol' in a function call?

Tags: java, overloading

I was implementing method overloading with 2 different datatypes. This is how I ended up with the code. 
But now it cannot find the symbols c and d . any help ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class LargestOfTwoTest{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("Enter two numbers, and I wiil show you which one's largest!\n");
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");
        double a = scan.nextDouble();
        double b = scan.nextDouble();

        if (a==(Math.floor(a))){
            int c = (int) a;
        }
        else{
            double c = a;
        }

        if (b==(Math.floor(b))){
            int d = (int) b;
        }
        else {
            double d = b;
        }

        System.out.print("Largest of the numbers is "+largest(c,d));
    }




    public static int largest(int x, int y){
        if (x>y)
            return x;
            //System.out.print("Largest of the numbers is "+x);
        else 
            return y;
            //System.out.print("Largest of the numbers is "+y);
    }
    public static double largest(double x, double y){
        if (x>y)
            return x;
            //System.out.print("Largest of the numbers is "+x);
        else 
            return y;
            //System.out.print("Largest of the numbers is "+y);
    }
}
```

Shows error in this line

```
System.out.print("Largest of the numbers is "+largest(c,d));
```

..

LargestOfTwoTest.java:29: error: cannot find symbol

( c and d)

Comment: You've declared `c` and  `d` out of scope for your invocation of `largest`, this has nothing to do with overloading.

Comment: In a single scope, you can only have one declaration of a variable. Your attempt to create different declarations by putting the declarations in an `if` won't work because the `if` blocks are separate scopes and the declaration goes out of scope as soon as the block is done.

Comment: You should rephrase your title to be question specific, or your going to keep getting downvoted. Just a friendly heads up.

Comment: ah got it , thanks guys

Comment: is there a datatype in java , that can store both integer and double .
P.S The program is for my assignment , and I'm just starting to practice Java, so feel free to help .

Comment: Integer and Double both extend Number. But what are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: Find the largest among the two inputted numbers, using function overloading concept(input float values and int values) :- this is the exact question my university made for assignments. :V

And I came up with this algorithm. But int and double gave me some trouble , like when overloading , I didn't know what to do.

Comment: So is the purpose to find the largest of two numbers, or to demonstrate that you grasp the concept of method overloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestOfTwo {

    private Scanner scanner;
    private Number a;
    private Number b;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        LargestOfTwo app = new LargestOfTwo();
        app.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        readInputs();
        Number largest = compare(a, b);
        System.out.print("Largest of the numbers is: " + largest);
    }

    private void readInputs() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter two numbers, and I will show you which one is largest\n");
        a = readInput();
        b = readInput();
    }

    private Number readInput() {
        Double d = scanner.nextDouble();
        if (d == Math.floor(d)) {
            return d.intValue();
        } else {
            return d;
        }
    }

    private Number compare(Number x, Number y) {
        if (new BigDecimal(x.floatValue()).compareTo(new BigDecimal(y.floatValue())) > 0) {
            return x;
        } else {
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: omg, thanks for this ,
I couldn't run the program , but still made progress, thank you..

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/lP9is  this is the problem now , since I can't figure out why , I'm submitting this for my assignment, The logic is strong with this one. :)

Comment: Also, my code creates an instance of LargestOfTwo which has fields for the scanner, and the two numbers. These are assigned within the method readInputs(). You copied the method but not the required fields so that won't work.